# How determine css text of each node in html

Tags: c#, html, css, loops

How can I iterate over HTML nodes of a web page and get the CSS Text of each node in it? I need something like what Firebug is doing, if you click on a Node, it gives you complete list of all CSS Texts associated with that Node (even inherited styles).

My main problem is not actually iterating over HTML nodes. I am doing it with [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) library. I just need to get complete CSS for each node.

p.s. I am sorry, I should have explained that I want to do this in C# (not javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following code snippet useful for all element in the page and 'CurrentStyle' property of them shows their computed style:

```
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)axWebBrowser1.Document;
        var body = (HTMLBody)doc.body;//current style

        var childs = (IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection)body.childNodes;
        var currentelementType = (HTMLBody)childs.item(0);
        var width = currentelementType.currentStyle.width;
```

Note that according to my prev post axWebBrowser1 is a WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current styles for an element, look into `getComputedStyle()`, but if you want the inheritance too then you may have to implement the style cascade. Firebug does quite a lot of work behind the scenes to generate what you see!

Comment: Actually, I hadn't noticed that you seem to be doing the parsing in .NET. In that case, you'll either have to find a library that implements CSS rules, or implement the cascade yourself.

Comment: I implemented the cascading rules, including the `getComputedStyle` method, in my CSS parser at http://www.modeltext.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You can try `for (property in objName)` operator as seen [here](http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/010305.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can simply get "all" CSS properties using JavaScript to be honest, you could look into the `[DOMNode].currentStyle`, `[DOMNode].style` and `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle` thingamajiggy's. They should contain the 'current' style they had. What you could then do is have an array of all CSS properties you want to test and simply loop them through a function of your own that gets the CSS property for everything using forementioned methods (depending on which browser). I usually attempt the `DOMNode.style[property]` first as this is "inline" javascript and always rules over everything, then I sniff if the browser uses the `.currentStyle` method or `.getComputedStyle` and use the correct one.

It's not perfect and you might need to clean up some things (height: auto; to the actual current height, some browsers might return RGB colours instead of HEX) etc.

So, yes, I don't know of anything prefab that you can use in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CSS text from the style attribute like this:

```
node.getAttribute('style')
```

Or if you want style you can iterate through the keys and values in

```
node.style
```

If you want to grab the entire computed style of the element and not just the CSS applied in the style attribute, read [this article](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/) on computed and cascaded styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebBrowser control in C# to access the htm document object and cast its body tag as following:

```
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)axWebBrowser1.Document;
var body = (HTMLBody)doc.body;
```

But before that you should add com refrence: MSHTML to you project.
here you could access body.currentStyle that show you all its styles that might be css or inline styles.