# get html element font-size

Tags: c#, html, dom

I would like to get the font-size for an html element in a web page, for example a `<p>` tag.
This should be valid even for element without a `style` or `class` attribute, so it has to know dynamically inherited css attributes.

I've tried with html agilitypack, a very good lib, but of course it doesn't consider css rendering. Tried also with WPF webbrowser, but it seems it cannot get font size for every element, and for many of them it returns a percentage.

Javascript `getComputedStyle()` is not suitable since all should run server side.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the `currentStyle` property? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905766/how-determine-css-text-of-each-node-in-html/1905782#1905782

Comment: why do you need this? The context of when you want this is important?

Comment: the context is extracting text article from web pages, so it's important to know the size of the text being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Element.prototype.getStyle = function (prop) {
    if (document.defaultView) 
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this, null)[prop];
    else 
        return this.currentStyle[prop];
}
```

call:

```
document.getElementById("div1").getStyle("font-size");
```

Comment: Thanks but it must be a server side process, I need C# to be aware of text size in a web page...

Comment: If I understand you well, You cannot do it with C# only... why you don't using ajax?